# How to recognize selected view in onItemClick in Android

Tags: android, android-listview, listviewitem, onitemclicklistener

I have a list view and each row of it has 3 buttons(Click able Image Views) making different actions if they are clicked.

I have a trouble with it because I don´t know how to recognize if the user click the button for delete or edit the element. I mean, How can I get the View that the user selected?

I tried with the parameters of onItemClick but I´m get stuck in there.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int pos, long id)
```

Thanks.[image]

Comment: Are you trying to find out which button was clicked? or the view in which the button was clicked?

Comment: i didn't get you, can you explain bit more that hat exactly you are looking for.

Comment: @fremmedehenvendelser I´m trying to find out wich button of the raw in the listview was clicked

Comment: You won't have that problem if you set different onClickListeners to those buttons. And you shouldn't consume that event in `onItemClick`.

Comment: @fremmedehenvendelser I tried to do so but selecting a button just allowed me to edit or delete the last row of listview

Comment: look at [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html#onItemClick%28android.widget.AdapterView%3C?%3E,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long%29)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding tags to your buttons and in onClickListener call view.getTag().

Answer (score 1):

I did like to work with `LinearLayout` and do something like this :

```
private void setElements() {
    for (Element elem : listElements) {
        View view = li.inflate(R.layout.item_3_object, null);//view represents a line from your list
        Button bt1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.bt1);
        Button bt2 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.bt2);
        Button bt3 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.bt3);
        bt1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // your code
            }
        });
        // set listeners for the other buttons too
        listView.addView(view); //is the LinearLayout element to fill with lines
    }
}
```

Comment: how can i get the position of that button or row in the the listview? I need to know that for delete the product of the ArrayList. Thanks.

Comment: you can use the typical for element `for (int i = 0; i < listElements.size(); i++)`

Answer (score 0):

```
private Button button;

button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                        button1Action(); // do your action here
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want element from the `ListView` Row as Clickable you have define it Into your `view` Like this: i.e Your `Adapter` you are using to inflate your `view`

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        ContentHolder chld=null;
        View row =  convertView;

        final int p=position;
        ContactModel rowItem = getItem(position);
        if(row==null)
        {
            chld=new ContentHolder();

            LayoutInflater inflate=(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            row=inflate.inflate(textViewResourceId,null);   

            chld.btn=(Button)row.findViewById(R.id.listViewButton_http);

            row.setTag(chld);

        }else{
            chld=(ContentHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        Button b1=(Button)row.findViewById(R.id.listViewButton_http);

        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

          //similary call your other Button here and it is DONE
    }
```

Hope this could help

Answer (score 0):

The view-parameter is the one you want.

`v.getId()` delivers you the id of the clicked button.

For example, use:

```
if(v.getId() == R.id.buttonDelete) {
    //your code for delete button here
}
```